# Connecting to SOAP with WSS using two pem files

Tags: java, soap, authorization, ws-security

A 3rd-party-app, which uses [OASIS Web Services Security (WSS)](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/wss/) for their SOAP authorization, provided me with following two pem files:

**ws-client.pem**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
VQQKDAxCZWFyaW5nUG9pbnQxFDASBgNVBAcMC0TDvHNzZWxkb3JmMQkwBwYDVQQI
[..]
CCsGAQUFBwMCBggrBgEFBQcDCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAY8MiqxLIE+dQ
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
XKJyj28HAgMBAAECggEATF3hM/l2mIDFkJ69kskJUep/+ejl33AXVc9akY7gocLV
[..]
P+htLANmvC29Z5eFgkotZsAQoRi+L4gNsH1kbWHxcYA6YWRCHtpTYsa6/agUnywq
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**ws-server.pem**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
cmcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRFMB4XDTE3MTExNDExMjA1NloXDTI3MTExNDExMjA1Nlow
[..]
z6RWmsrSfLXGAM5QL4CCDzMth2AP8WzksMzW6dD6qK5/X9yD3g2GRXbHbtnvl6fk
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The last two days I tried a lot of different approaches, followed several examples.. using curl, nodejs, java etc.. with no success.

**This is my latest code:**

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader

import java.security.*
import java.security.cert.Certificate
import java.security.cert.CertificateException
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate

class WsSecurityHandler {

    private static final char[] KSPASSWORD = null

    WsSecurityHandler() {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())
    }

    private PrivateKey getPrivateKey() throws IOException {
        InputStream pemClientInput = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pem/ws-client.pem")
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(pemClientInput, "UTF8")
        PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(reader)
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) pemReader.readObject()
        pemReader.close()
        return privateKey
    }

    private X509Certificate getPublicCertificate() throws IOException {
        InputStream pemServerInput = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pem/ws-server.pem")
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(pemServerInput, "UTF8")
        PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(reader)
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) pemReader.readObject()
        pemReader.close()
        return certificate
    }


    void initKeyStore() throws IOException {
        PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey()
        X509Certificate certificate = getPublicCertificate() 
        Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[1]
        chain[0] = certificate

        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")
            ks.load(null, KSPASSWORD)
            ks.setKeyEntry("FooBar", privateKey, KSPASSWORD, chain)
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

which fails at line

```
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) pemReader.readObject()
```

with:

> Exception in thread "main" 
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot
>   cast object with class
>   'org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject' to class
>   'java.security.PrivateKey'

I am somehow getting the impression that I misunderstood a big part in this topic.. So it comes to this kind of embarrassing question:
How exactly do I prepare my application to be able to connect to this WSS-SOAP-API?